# Modelling commands in REST api

Tags: rest, api-design

I am looking for a good way to model commands that change the status of a resource in a REST api. I have scoured the internet and found various solutions, I would like to get feedback on the pros/cons of these.

Consider a resource that has an "isActive" state. The resource can be made active if its current "isActive" state is false and visa versa.

Solutions:

1. Client PUTs|PATCHes to the resource with the new state.

   - PROS: Very simple.
   - CONS: No nice way to provide hypermedia to indicate to the client that the resource can be activated/deactivated.
2. Client POSTs to resource/{id}/activate. (No body required.)

   - PROS: Hypermedia driven. Intuitive.
   - CONS: Not truly RESTful (as action is conveyed in the Uri).
3. Client POSTs to resources/active or resources/inactive. (The body contains the id of the resource that should be added to the active resources collection)

   - PROS: Hypermedia driven.
   - CONS: Not as intuitive as option 2.
4. Client POSTs or DELETEs to resources/{id}/isactive to indicate whether the resource is active or not.

   - PROS: Hypermedia driven.

Are they any other ways that you know of?

I quite like option 3, but have not seen this method anywhere online, so maybe it violates some REST principle!

Comment: This is mostly my opinion but my favorite design I’ve seen in the wild is to have relatively stateless entities and an event system that produces side effects on entities. So it would be somewhere between 2 and 3. You’d basically be posting and creating activate or deactivate events to your api. This also have a side effect of keeping natural logs of actions.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful:

> Treat it like a sub-resource with RESTful principles. For example, GitHub's API lets you [star a gist](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#star-a-gist) with `PUT /gists/{id}/star` and [unstar](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#unstar-a-gist) with `DELETE /gists/{id}/star`.

Applying this approach to your case:

- Activating: `PUT /resources/{id}/active`
- Deactivating: `DELETE /resources/{id}/active`